# How to create a swift cocoapods library that is dependent on another pod?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to create a library using pods, as per the instructions in this tutorial:

http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html

Incidentally, the library I am creating is dependent on another pod, and I'm not sure how to account for that.

I've tried following the instructions in the tutorial above, and then edited the Podfile so that it includes the other pod I need, and when I run "pod install" the pod does indeed install and is added to the project.

However, my library is still filled with "Use of undeclared type" errors whenever a variable that is dependent on the "external" pods exists.

Any idea how to solve this issue, in Swift?

Comment: Did you try adding the "dependency" entry? http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency